# Passing data from one model to another

Tags: java

In my task I have to pass some data from one model to another, where each model contains lists:

```
List<VisualProcess> vProcesses = new ArrayList<VisualProcess>();
    for (Process process : processList) {
                VisualProcess vProcess = new VisualProcess();
                vProcess.setId(process.getId());
                List<VisualProcessStep> steps = new ArrayList<VisualProcessStep>();
                List<VisualProcessStepConnection> connections = new ArrayList<VisualProcessStepConnection>();
                for(ProcessStep processStep : process.getSteps()){
                    VisualProcessStep vps = new VisualProcessStep();
                    vps.setActivityId(processStep.getActivityId());
                    vps.setDefinition(processStep.getDefinition());
                    vps.setId(processStep.getId());
                    vps.setParameters(processStep.getParameters());
                    vps.setStatus(processStep.getStatus());
                    for (Activity activity : process.getActivities()) {
                        if (activity.getId().equals(vps.getActivityId())){
                            vps.setActivityName(activity.getName());
                            vps.setActivityRealization(activity.getRealization());  
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    steps.add(vps);
                    for (ProcessStep nextProcessStep : processStep.getNextSteps()) {
                        VisualProcessStepConnection vpsc = new VisualProcessStepConnection();
                        vpsc.setFrom(processStep.getId());
                        vpsc.setTo(nextProcessStep.getId());
                        connections.add(vpsc);
                    }
                }
                vProcess.setSteps(steps);
                vProcess.setConnections(connections);
                vProcesses.add(vProcess);
            }
```

However, while I think it looks awful, I don't have any other ideas as to making it more elegant. Another issue is about the size of the method: Would it be better to split it into several, smaller methods?

Comment: Be sure, you'll get an answer, but in the meantime please improve you title (you can edit your question anytime; just avoid changes which would invalidate already given answers).

Comment: Are you on Java 6/7/8?

Comment: i'm using java 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it too awful code?

Not too awful and not even bad, but the huge wall of code looks ugly.

There are a few minor issues like missing blank after "for" in

```
for(ProcessStep processStep : process.getSteps()){
```

and before "{" in

```
if (activity.getId().equals(vps.getActivityId())){
```

but that's something your IDE can do for you (Ctrl-Shift-F in Eclipse).

---

Otherwise, all you need is to extract a few methods like

```
private VisualProcessStep toVisualProcessStep(Process process, ProcessStep processStep) {
    VisualProcessStep result = new VisualProcessStep();
    result.setActivityId(processStep.getActivityId());
    result.setDefinition(processStep.getDefinition());
    result.setId(processStep.getId());
    result.setParameters(processStep.getParameters());
    result.setStatus(processStep.getStatus());
    for (Activity activity : process.getActivities()) {
        if (activity.getId().equals(result.getActivityId())) {
            result.setActivityName(activity.getName());
            result.setActivityRealization(activity.getRealization());  
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This can be repeated many times and you surely shouldn't extract everything. When the methods don't get used elsewhere, this is very subjective as you're trading a too long method for too many methods.

The sweet spot are methods somewhere about 15 lines long. As all the methods do is just copying everything and there isn't much to think about, they may be a bit longer. I'd personally split it into probably 3 methods.

---

Obviously, there may be a smarter way avoiding the manual copying. It surely can be done via reflection, but reflection is verbose and slow and ugly itself, so I wouldn't consider it for this task.

Maybe you could create a constructor (or a factory method) for `VisualProcessStep`?

Comment: thank you, it's the most perfect answer which i ever waited

Comment: The suggested method is just missing the `process` argument. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be better to split it into several, smaller methods?

In your context, definitely. A cursory look at your method yield the following pseudo-code:

```
For each process in processList
    Create a new VisualProcess instance with some of process's properties
    For each step in this process
        Create a VisualProcessStep instance with some of step's properties
        If this process has an associated Activity, set it to the VisualProcessStep instance
        Create VisualProcessStepConnection instances between the current step
                and its next steps and add them to a List called connections
        Add the VisualProcessStep instance to a List called steps
    Add steps and connections to the VisualProcess instance
    Add the VisualProcess instance to a List called vProcesses
```

Each step can be a smaller method in itself. The *developer* benefits of having smaller methods in your case is that it clearly isolates what fields/properties are required for each 'stage', which in turn allows you to better understand how you code works or can be rearranged. The *JVM* benefits of having smaller methods is that the JVM can decide when and how to inline method calls optimally to enhance the overall performance.

My suggestions below are going to be Java 8-based, primarily because I like to use such opportunities to showcase how much simpler can external iterations be done using [`Stream`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). If you happen to be on older Java versions, the conversion shouldn't be too hard in any case, and I'm quite sure a quick check at StackOverflow should offer some help. ;)

Let's start by starting from the end of the steps covered in the pseudo-code...

---

**Create VisualProcessStepConnection instances between the current step and its next steps**

In your current code, you are iterating through the next steps of the current `ProcessStep` and then constructing a new `VisualProcessStepConnection` object for each of them. To simplify the creation of the object, you can either give it a constructor that takes in two `ProcessStep` instances, or use a `static` method to do so. The suggestion below combines both approaches:

```
public class VisualProcessStepConnection {
    public static of(ProcessStep from, ProcessStep to) {
        return new VisualProcessStepConnection(from.getId(), to.getId());
    }
}
```

In turn, you can then create a `getConnections()` method for `ProcessStep` that can iterate through its `getNextSteps()` (assuming it's one of the Collection classes, like a `List`) to generate the desired output:

```
public class ProcessStep {
    public List<VisualProcessStepConnection> getConnections() {
        getNextSteps().stream().map(v -> VisualProcessStepConnection.of(this, v))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This takes each element of `getNextSteps()`, [`map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) it into the required `VisualProcessStepConnection` object, and then [`collect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) each of the result [into a `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

With these two methods, you can already replace the `for`-loop as such:

```
connections.addAll(processStep.getConnections());
/*
for (ProcessStep nextProcessStep : processStep.getNextSteps()) {
    VisualProcessStepConnection vpsc = new VisualProcessStepConnection();
    vpsc.setFrom(processStep.getId());
    vpsc.setTo(nextProcessStep.getId());
    connections.add(vpsc);
}
*/
```

---

**If this process has an associated Activity, set it to the VisualProcessStep instance**

Currently, you are looping through `process.getActivities()` to see if there is a matching activity. I will suggest creating a new method that also accepts the activity ID to look for (assuming it has its own type, e.g. `ActivityId`):

```
public class Process {
    public Optional<Activity> getActivityForId(ActivityId activityId) {
        return getActivities().stream().filter(v -> v.getId().equals(activityId))
                                        .findFirst();
    }
}
```

This [`filter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) on your `getActivities()` uses the same current condition, and [optionally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) returns the first element found. This `Optional<Activity>` wrapper-object can then be utilized to set the activity-related properties on a `VisualProcessStep`, provided you have a method there too that can perform the operation on an `Activity` instance:

```
public class VisualProcessStep {
    private void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        setActivityName(activity.getName());
        setActivityRealization(activity.getRealization());
    }
}
```

When you combine both, you get the following simplification:

```
process.getActivityForId(vps.getActivityId()).ifPresent(vps::setActivity);
/*
for (Activity activity : process.getActivities()) {
    if (activity.getId().equals(vps.getActivityId())){
        vps.setActivityName(activity.getName());
        vps.setActivityRealization(activity.getRealization());  
        break;
    }
}
*/
```

`setActivity()` is being called as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) here.

---

**Create a VisualProcessStep instance with some of step's properties**

This part is relatively straightforward, you can encapsulate the logic of setting the properties *from* a `ProcessStep` instance *to* a `VisualProcessStep` instance as a method inside the latter:

```
public class VisualProcessStep {        
    public static VisualProcessStep from(ProcessStep processStep) {
        VisualProcessStep vps = new VisualProcessStep();
        vps.setActivityId(processStep.getActivityId());
        vps.setDefinition(processStep.getDefinition());
        vps.setId(processStep.getId());
        vps.setParameters(processStep.getParameters());
        vps.setStatus(processStep.getStatus());
        return vps;
    }
}
```

The code in your original loop can then be just:

```
VisualProcessStep vps = VisualProcessStep.from(processStep);
/*
VisualProcessStep vps = new VisualProcessStep();
vps.setActivityId(processStep.getActivityId());
vps.setDefinition(processStep.getDefinition());
vps.setId(processStep.getId());
vps.setParameters(processStep.getParameters());
vps.setStatus(processStep.getStatus());
*/
```

---

**Putting it altogether, #1**

After you have *extracted out the derivation logic* into small methods on your model classes, you should have something similar to the following:

```
List<VisualProcess> vProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
for (Process process : processList) {
    VisualProcess vProcess = new VisualProcess();
    vProcess.setId(process.getId());
    List<VisualProcessStep> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<VisualProcessStepConnection> connections = new ArrayList<>();
    for(ProcessStep processStep : process.getSteps()){
        VisualProcessStep vps = VisualProcessStep.from(processStep);
        process.getActivityForId(vps.getActivityId()).ifPresent(vps::setActivity);
        steps.add(vps);
        connections.addAll(processStep.getConnections());
    }
    vProcess.setSteps(steps);
    vProcess.setConnections(connections);
    vProcesses.add(vProcess);
}
```

From this, the three 'main' steps that you need to do for each step becomes clearer.

---

**Putting it altogether, #2**

If you were to take the whole `Stream`-based approach one step further, you will realize that perhaps, even your looping for the steps can be 'converted' too:

```
List<VisualProcess> vProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
for (Process process : processList) {
    VisualProcess vProcess = new VisualProcess();
    vProcess.setId(process.getId());
    List<VisualProcessStep> vpsList = process.getSteps().stream()
            .map(VisualProcessStep::from)
            .peek(v -> process.getActivityForId(v.getActivityId()).ifPresent(v::setActivity))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    vProcess.setSteps(vpsList);
    List<VisualProcessStepConnection> connectionsList = process.getSteps().stream()
            .map(ProcessStep::getConnections).flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    vProcess.setConnections(connectionsList);
    vProcesses.add(vProcess);
}
```

In this case, we are streaming on `process.getSteps()` twice, once to map it to `VisualProcessStep` objects, and the other to `collect()` and [`flatMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) into the `VisualProcessStepConnection` objects. This lets us eliminate the temporary `steps` and `connections` variables. Somewhat conveniently, we can also perform a [`peek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) on the `VisualProcessStep` objects to set the activity-related properties before collecting them into a `List`.

***Finally***, one can attempt to complete the whole `Stream`-based metamorphosis on the `processList`, but I will leave that to the discerning reader seeing as how this is already quite a lengthy answer.

---

**Conclusion**

It's always good to conceptualize what are the *steps* in your chunk(s) of code, and then wrap them into their own methods. This helps to facilitate an appreciation of your own code, which could uncover inefficiencies (e.g. doing something twice) or potential bugs (checking for a property in one place but not the other). More importantly, it lets you easily perform unit testing on smaller slices of your code, so that you can safely modify these smaller chunks in the future to be more efficient with the assurance that you wouldn't be introducing bugs.